# How can I make my params in .env required?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I use dotenv
I create a .env file in the root directory of my project.
And I want my build will crash if I haven't some values in .env file

How can I make my env params required?

Answer (score 1):

You can exit docker build process if .env is empty. Below also checking for a particular variable in .env if exist.

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY .env .env
RUN if [ -s .env ] ; then  \
    echo "Env file is not empty"; \
    #to check for particular variable in .env
      if grep "var1" .env > /dev/null ;\
         then \
         #you can exit here if var1 not exist.
         echo "var1 exist" ;\
      fi ; \
   echo "Values checked....." ; \
   else \
      echo "Env is empty. Process going to exit..." \
      echo "value in .env file" \
      make; exit 1 ; \
   fi
RUN cat .env
```